# In Inkscape is there a way to preserve file name of imported images?

Tags: inkscape, svg, import

I import (embed) a lot of jpg's and png's to Inkscape, many of them visually similar to each other. When you select an image, the tool-tip/status bar message will say something like: "image 1000 x 1400: embedded in layer..." 
Is there a way to get Inkscape to keep the original name of the image, so that if it was 'Lincoln-3' on your desktop it is 'Lincoln-3' in your drawing? The file name is preserved when Linking, but that is not an option for me.

Comment: How do you feel about renaming Layer 3 to Lincoln-3 ?

Comment: Not a bad idea, but I tend to have hundreds of objects in a single drawing, so... But this is a bit better than the suggestion below since the name WOULD appear in the Status bar after naming it.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do that within the GUI as far as I know, but perhaps an extension could be written to do it automatically. Unfortunately I can't help you there.

However, there is manual work around.

1. When you import an image, Link to the file initially
2. Select the object, and take look at the file name in the status bar
3. Open the Object Properties panel (Shift+Ctrl+O), and type the file name in the 'Title' field, or even in the image ID field (as long as each image ID is unique).
4. Click Set
5. Right click the image and choose 'Embed Image'

Comment: Not a bad workaround, and in some contexts I might use that. But for everyday use I think I'll stick to my own workaround, which is to just type the image name in text and place it on/under the image, like a caption, or group it to the image.